# FHIR resource for No Data

Tags: hl7-fhir

My FHIR Rest API can search and return FHIR resources like [Patient] and [Encounter]. When a search for resources is done, there are instances where no data is found. In such cases, what is the FHIR resource I can send to specify that there is NO data for the search?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The response to a FHIR search should be a `Bundle` resource with `"type": "searchset"`. You can find the relevant section of the spec [here](https://hl7.org/fhir/search.html#Introduction). If the search has no results you should simply return a Bundle with an empty `entry` list, and `"total": 0`

Comment: You can return an OperationOutcome with further information if you want (for text display to a human)